# Setting a Umask value for a particular directory and not a user

Tags: linux, unix, centos

I have one directory named as MAIN_OUTPUT. I have a JAVA application which will create some files and directories under MAIN_OUTPUT. The users submitting the java applications are different all the times. Now the requirement is to set the umask for this particular directory(MAIN_OUTPUT) as 0002, so that all the files generated will have read-write permissions. Can anyone suggest a way for this?

Thanks,
Ankur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want everybody to be able to write into that directory, but that the files remained owned by directory owner, you could do from your Unix/Linux terminal:

```
chmod 1775 <complete path>/MAIN_OUTPUT
```

Then from time to time, directory owner can come here and give permissions to everyone, since he still owns the file.

You may find more expertise on http://unix.stackexchange.com though.